# Function pointer returning behaviour

Tags: c, pointers

if I have a C function where I return a pointer to a malloc-ated memory location like -->

```
int *example0{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(10);
    ptr[0] = '1';
    return ptr;
}
```

call that function twice and at the first function call do not free() the ptr

```
int example2{
    int *exmple = example0();
}

int example3{
    int *exmple2 = example0();
    free(exmple2);
}
```

does C run the compiled example0 function twice or does C only return the ptr to the not free()-ed pre "filled" memory-location at the second function call?

If: C does run the function twice, how can I not waste computing time at running the function twice?

Comment: Please fix the syntax in your question. It's currently not valid C.

Comment: Your functions doesn't actually do any thing, so discussing how to rewrite it doesn't really make any sense without more context. If you want to avoid a `malloc` in a function, one way is to let the caller pass a pointer to buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does C run the compiled example0 function twice or does C only return the ptr to the not free()-ed pre "filled" memory-location at the second function call?

If you call the function twice, your program calls the function twice, and you also `malloc`ate memory twice. It doesn't know about the other time you called the function.

> If: C does run the function twice, how can I not waste computing time at running the function twice?

Don't call the function twice? Alternately, if what you really do want is the buffer to be only allocated once, [you can make it a `static` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572550/51685).

Comment: static variables are usually a bad idea as it makes function non-reentrant which is a problem in the multitasking environment. BTW in this case, `static` does not change anything as `malloc` will be called twice anyway causing the memory leak.

Comment: @0___________ Yes, global state (which include static variables) can be a bad idea. As for the BTW, yup - OP will of course need to do other changes than just declare the variable static.

Comment: then you should show him what to do to avoid multiple `malloc`s I do not think that he is able to do so (judging from the question)